# How to backup at scheme level on DB2 Warehouse On Cloud?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, database-backups, dashdb

We are using DB2 Warehouse On Cloud, Flex Performance Plan.
By default, daily full online backup and retain last seven backup images are provided by DB2 Warehouse On the Cloud.

However, we need a more flexible backup strategy. Besides a full backup, is there any other way to backup some specific schemas?

According to the [Db2 Warehouse knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/app_backup.html), a command `db_backup` can do schema level backup. But I don't know how to use this command as I can not log in to the db2 server directly.

Comment: That section you reference refers to "Db2 Warehouse" and not the "on Cloud" service. What is the use case?

Comment: If the "db_backup" is not suitable for DB2 Warehouse On Cloud, is there any way to backup and restore on schema level and table level on DB2 Warehouse On Cloud?